# how to check the value is empty in Item()?

Tags: python

I have a `item = Item()`
and I want to check if it's empty,but with error.
I think it's because `item['mvid']` is empty
so how can I check this???
try except??

```
    if not item['mvid'] :
        log.msg("title={}".format(item['title']) ,level=log.WARNING)


    if not item['mvid'] :
  File "/Users/some/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 50, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
exceptions.KeyError: 'mvid'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValueError` here means that the key 'mvid' was never set in your dict. This is different than if `item['mvid']` was set to `None` or an empty string for example.

You can do:

```
if 'mvid' not in item:
    # Do something
```

Depending on your use case, an alternate approach could be to catch the exception:

```
try:
   print item['mvid']
except ValueError:
   # Handle error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

`if item.get("mvid", None):
    # do something`